# How do I convert an Object to JSON excluding an attribute

Tags: java, json, web-services, jackson

I need to convert an Object to JSON without some specific attributes. I have tried following code.

```
public static String toJson(Object obj) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        String output = null;
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        SerializationConfig cfg = om.getSerializationConfig();
        cfg.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
        om.setSerializationConfig(cfg);

        output = om.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(obj);

        return output;

    }
```

but i need to exclude one attribute from **Object obj** to be generated as json. How do i achieve that ? I would really appreciate help !!

Comment: Try @JsonIgnore is you're using Jackson - which I highly recommend.  See: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations

Comment: thanks @david.. it works only if i put JSONIgnore annotation on field getters